# Redirects & server migration Windows -> Linux

Tags: linux, windows, .htaccess, redirect, plesk

I am about to migrate/move the data from a Windows Plesk server to a Linux Plesk server. Which in itself is a humongous pain in the a***!

On top of that I am developing a new version of a website on the current WPlesk(Windows Plesk). It is being developed in Wordpress. The current website is running a system called nemCMS, which requires a WPlesk to run.

When I move the data and domain to the new LPlesk(Linux Plesk), will I then be able to set up the htaccess redirects from the old - now non existing nemCMS site & URLs - without losing page rank etc.?

I hope you are able to help me out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially migration from WPlesk to LPlesk and vice versa is not supported. You can do it only with creation the same domain/hosting on destination server and migration site content manually. Be sure that site is not connected to any Windows only web technologies :)

For redirection you can just change type of hosting for domain on WPlesk to Forwarding.

Comment: Thanks. :) I will try to make the question a bit more specific.

The scenario is that I am migrating from Wplesk to Lplesk. 

On the current Wplesk, one of the sites use a windows only CMS. So for obvious reasons I will not be able to transfer it to the Lplesk.

So, I have created a new WP version of the site. Will I be able to set up an htaccess file with redirects from the "OLD" site on the Wplesk to the new site on the Lplesk? To avoid losing pakerank etc.

Comment: As far as I know IIS does not support htaccess. But you can try to use URLRewrite module. And Forwarding type of WPlesk hosting shouldn't affect pakerank, etc.